# Can I create a Power Geo Logging Configuration Entity (powergeologgingconfiguration) in CRM automatically when the user in logged in?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to create a `powergeologgingconfiguration` entity when the user is logged in the crm. I don't want to do this with plugin or with something else.

I am not finding even enough information for this entity, and the relation of this entity with the user entity.

Comment: Hi, did you get a chance to check my answer? Can you close all your questions by upvoting/accepting the answer that helped you or by answering them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using this [third party solution from PowerObjects.](https://www.powerobjects.com/guides/powergeolog/). It’s a simple install, configure, use & pay Managed solution.

It starts collecting automatically the data like IP, latitude, longitude, etc on user login & alert notification for geo-fencing is possible. Configuration entity will be used by the third party to store configuration data, you should not be touching that.

Probably you can capture your own data in their entities, using JavaScript in form load & create records in required entities using web api. It’s not recommended though to interfere in 3rd party entities.